# How can I set up an alias for imports in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, python-import

I want my project to work in two different situations. It should work as a standalone library, but also as sub package of a larger project. The main use case is that of a standalone library, where its internal imports should be of the form

```
from my_library import sub_package
```

When using the code as sub package of a larger project, these imports don't work as there is no global name `my_library`. Instead, I would have to use relative or absolute imports, for example

```
from large_project.my_library import sub_package
```

Let's assume I wrote my library as shown in the first example. How can I overwrite importing behavior when running as part of a larger project to automatically adjust import paths?

Comment: What do you mean by `importing behavior`? Do you mean for example 'execute different functions' when importing from subdirectory?

Comment: @MatrixTai The goal is to make the import shown in the first box work even when the code is used as a sub package in another project rather than as an external dependency. I could imagine using an import hook to catch all imports and then replace `my_library` by `__module__.my_library` or similar, but I'm not familiar with these rarely used features of Python.

Comment: It is impossible to make first one work without adding anyline (like `sys.path.append()` or `importlib.import_module`), as when you put `my_library` into another project, python treat it as `module` and `sub_package` is `submodule`, you can't access submodule without stating the parent of it.

Comment: @MatrixTai Exactly. I'm looking for a snippet that I can add to my_library/__init__.py when using it as sub package, without having to convert all the internal includes manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @MatrixTai's suggestion of adding the parent directory of the package to the the module path, I came up with this dynamic solution. At the top of `my_library/__init__.py`:

```
# Make package global even if used as a sub package to enable short imports.
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

We have to navigate up two directories here to do from the `my_library/__init__.py` to `my_library` and from there to its parent direction, where imports will find the library.

Comment: How to make `PyCharm` understand it also?

Comment: Mark your sub workpackage parent directory as Source folder in Project structure.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have much choice.

If you want to reference the `my_library.py` anywhere, there is 2 method (as I known) can do similar work.

---

1: add system path. Like those module you installed by `pip`. `pip` module is installed in `/Python/Scripts`. You can add a new path or simply put `my_library.py` into one of the path. For adding, that's in `Computer(right-click)-> Properties -> Environment Variable -> Choose Path and Click Edit`

(Though you may not want to use this.)

---

2: Changing `__init__.py`, but still at least one line you must add in `my_library.py`.

For example,

```
/Directory
   /large_project
      -__init__.py #call this sub_init
      -my_library.py
   -__init__.py #call this main_init, this fake
   -main.py
```

In main_init,

```
import sys
sys.path.append('\\Directory\\large_project')
```

As main_init is not executed when you execute main.py (this is fake), so in main.py

```
import __init__
from my_library import sub_package
```

But as well you can take this main_init as the starter of library, like declaring `__all__`, etc.